# HTML::TokeParser not able to install from CPAN

Tags: perl, html-parsing, cpan

I am not able to install `HTML::TokeParser` this package from CPAN.

```
cpan[6]>   install    HTML::TokeParser


Running install for module 'HTML::TokeParser'


Running make for G/GA/GAAS/HTML-Parser-3.71.tar.gz


  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/HTML-Parser-3.71-0zUSqw


Could not make: Unknown error


Running make test
  Can't test with enter code here out successful make

Running make install


  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Can anyone help here?

Comment: remove `/root/.cpan/build/HTML-Parser-3.71-0zUSqw` and try again

Comment: @jens it worked. really thankful.  now could you please tell me why I encountered this. my system was fresh and had only some default installation

Answer (score -1):

you can try:

perl -MCPAN -e 'install HTML::TokeParser'

OR

```
Download the zipped tar file from one of the following:

http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.71/lib/HTML/TokeParser.pm
or
search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/HTML-Parser-3.71.tar.gz

Unzip the module as follows or use winzip:

       tar -zxvf HTML-Parser-3.71.tar.gz

The module can be installed using the standard Perl procedure:

    perl Makefile.PL
    make
    make test
    make install    # You may need to be root
    make clean      # or make realclean
```